# send result of ToList() from hub to client

Tags: entity-framework, linq, signalr

This is my class in `Entity Framework Code-Firts` (I made it smaller in question):

```
public class dslam
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("center")]
    public int centerId { get; set; }
    public center center { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [DisplayName("Title")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    [DisplayName("Type")]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(5)]
    [DisplayName("Port")]
    public string port { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    [DisplayName("Host")]
    public string host { get; set; }
}
```

This is client side code:

```
detailHub.client.setDSLAMInfo = function (liDslams) {
    alert('test');
}
```

If I use *dslam* class like this, `alert('test');` will trigger in my client side:

```
List<dslam> liDSLAMS = new List<dslam>();
liDSLAMS.Add(new dslam { title = "1", Type= "2", Port= "3"  });

var foo = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(liDSLAMS);
Clients.Client(hubConnectionId).setDSLAMInfo(foo);
```

But I can't use `ToList()`, it seems `ToList()` will break something and `alert('test');` will not trigger:

```
List<dslam> liDSLAMS = new List<dslam>();
liDSLAMS = ed.dslams.Where(x => x.centerId == 1).ToList();

//this line will not work properly I guess ToList(); broke something
//var foo = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(liDSLAMS);

Clients.Client(hubConnectionId).setDSLAMInfo(foo);
```

**Edit:**

`liDSLAMS` is not null:
[image]

Comment: I think you are getting NULL from  "ed.dslams.Where(x => x.centerId == 1)"  this method

Comment: @IrshadAhmed no, I tested it with breakpoint `liDSLAMS` have 3 records

Comment: what about this property  "public center center { get; set; }" are you getting value in it too ?

Comment: try this one "liDSLAMS = ed.dslams.Include(i=>i.center).Where(x => x.centerId == 1).ToList();"

Comment: @IrshadAhmed thank you but I don't think its because of null values, I used `include` too, but problem didn't solve

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem was with `Navigation Properties`.

It seems objects with *navigation property* are not able to be sent to client side. Also they are not convertible to *JSON*. Just select needed properties except *navigation properties*.

```
var liDSLAM = ed.dslams.Where(x => x.centerId == 1).Select(x => new { x.id, x.title }).ToList();
Clients.Client(hubConnectionId).setDSLAMInfo(liDSLAM);
```